# How do i get x random records with nHibernate Queryover

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Is there a nice succinct way to get random rows using query over? Something like this:

```
            .QueryOver<Stuff>(() => entity)
            .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Asc
            .Take(3)
            .List();
```

This doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this article:

http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/nhibernate-queryover-and-newid-or-rand.html

The key, I believe, is getting the query engine to generate the random value while executing the query, rather than specifying a value from the application (which may seem random to the application, but not to the query engine).

Comment: Thanks, the article was spot on